# Компиляция на Python кода Python

Tags: python, компиляция

Возможно ли из программы Python компилирования кода на том же Python?
То есть, предположим, что программа откуда-то получила код (например, считала из файла).

Можно ли как-то изнутри программы скомпилировать этот код?

Comment: Т.е. из .py сделать .pyc? А кто мешает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если нужен запуск плученного в виде текста Python кода то [eval](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval)

Comment: Только помните, что это небезопасно, если исходный код приходит извне.

Comment: Мда, незначительная такая оговорочка: "помните, что это небезопасно". )))

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы скомпилировать Питон код в байт-код, не запуская его на выполнение, можно использовать [`compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) для кода в строке, [`py_compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html) для модуля в файле, [`compileall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html) для дерева директорий с кодом.

Скомпилированный код можно отдать на выполнение в exec(), eval() функции. Скомпилированные `.pyc`/`.pyo` файлы могут быть выполнены напрямую python командой.

Пример из [`doctest` stdlib модуля](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13ecfbf9cf8fdc30fcf495a1f854d4c18d946da8/Lib/doctest.py#L1324-L1337):

```
# Don't blink!  This is where the user's code gets run.
exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single", compileflags, 1), test.globs)
```

Как правило компилировать вручную нет необходимости: `exec()`, `eval()`, `python` также принимают Питон код напрямую.

Чтобы создать AST представление кода, можно использовать [`ast.parse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse), что может быть полезно, к примеру, для [вычисления простых арифметических выражений](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/4279).