# Python — возможно ли скомпилировать *.py в *.pyc, при отсутствии некоторых нужных модулей, чтобы компилятор «закрыл на это глаза»?

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, декомпиляция

Зачем нужен этот изврат:
чтобы вносить изменения в приложение, не пересобирая его целиком из исходного кода, а то и вообще не имея такового. И также не декомпилируя его полностью (там целая куча этих *.pyc, а изменить нужно лишь 1).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Компиляция на Python кода Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/177354)

Comment: @andreymal И причем здесь eval?

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее, там не только про eval

Comment: cвязанный вопрос [Компиляция на Python кода Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/177354/23044)

Answer (score 2):

> чтобы компилятор «закрыл на это глаза»

Компилятор не делает никаких проверок кода, кроме синтаксических. Все ошибки импорта, несуществующих переменных и прочей такой дребедени происходят уже во время интерпретации заранее скомпилированного байткода.

А для компиляции байткода без его последующего запуска можно использовать модуль `py_compile`:

```
python -m py_compile yourfile.py
```

В Python 2 будет создан `yourfile.pyc`, в Python 3 будет создан `__pycache__/yourfile.cpython-3N.pyc`.

Также есть `compileall`, который умеет компилировать не только отдельные файлы, но и всё содержимое указанных каталогов рекурсивно:

```
python -m compileall путь-к-каталогу-с-модулями/
```

Comment: можно упомянуть, что практически никогда не нужно руками компилировать модули. Либо при установке автоматически генерится, либо при первом запуске новой версии.

Comment: @jfs к теме это не относится, тут особая задача

Comment: @SimAlllllll ответы на Stack Overflow предназначены не только и не столько для автора вопроса, а для посетителей из гугла с похожей проблемой (~95% трафика).